# Moving linked groups to another file

Tags: linked-data, groups

Anybody knows how to move linked groups to another files keeping it linked?
If i am appending the scene to another file all linked groups became a real objects which increased size of the scene dramatically!

Comment: weird, I've tried and it kept the linked groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When appending, uncheck "Localize All" in the lower left hand corner of the screen.

[image: Localize All]

Comment: No worries. Please click the check mark next to this answer to mark this question as answered.